# Can I use Oracle Stored procedure as a data source for Spotfire?

Tags: datasource, spotfire

Can I used Oracle Stored procedure as a data source for Spotfire ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use stored procedure in spotfire.

All You need to do is create a procedure object and then information link that uses stored procedure.

Note: Make sure that procedure doesn't have any output parameters

Thanks,
P